# How to get rid of Data-Block objects using pythong?

Tags: linked-data, data-blocks

I'd like to access all linked data blocks and remove them from scene using python, without deleting the actual data from my hard drive.

Context: I linked a grouped armature to my scene, made it a proxy so I could manipulate it. I later decided to delete the armature by selecting everything (hotkey: "A" ) and deleting. I'd like to know how to clean up such a mess. As you can see the Current scene view shows nothing is there.
[image]

However the data blocks still has everything in there.
[image]

Is there a way to access all Linked data blocks through python and unlinking them ?

Comment: Are you specifically looking to use Python or are you suggesting it because it seems like the only way?

Comment: @RayMairlot I am hoping to write script to run through the scene and find then remove objects that had been deleted but remained in data-blocks because they were linked. Does blender already have a function for that ? The point is I don't want to do that manually by selecting objects in outliner, in case a have a more convoluted scene and run into this problem.